# Having trouble implementing confirm() function to my form buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add `confirm()` function to 2 buttons that are located on a page used for updating the information of an image. The first button saves the information which has been changed about the image and the second button deletes the image. Both buttons are inside POST forms. Sadly, I am facing a couple of problems.

Firstly, even though the confirm box pops up when I click the button which saves the information, the form sends the POST request before I have clicked "Ok" or "Cancel" inside the confirm box and the information gets saved.

Secondly, I believe the delete button does the same thing. The box which asks me if I want to delete pops up, and even if I don't click anything, the image gets deleted from my database. Also if I click "Cancel" the effect is the same, the image gets deleted from my database.

Lastly, why does it say that `confirmFunction()` is not defined when it is inside `$(document).ready(function() {})` but works fine when it is outside it?

First form that uses the edit button.

```
<form action="{{ route('updateArtwork', $image) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class='label' for="artwork-tags">Tags</label>
        <input class='input' type="text" name="artwork-tags" placeholder="Tags" value='{{ $tagString }}'>
    </div>

    <button onclick='confirmFunction()' class='green-btn' type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Second form that uses the delete button.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('DeleteArtwork', $image->id)}}">
    <button onclick='confirmFunction()' class='red-btn' type="submit">Delete Image</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});

function confirmFunction() {
    confirm("Are you sure?");
}
```

Comment: (1) You need to actively prevent the form from submitting (the input is of type submit, so it will submit the form). You can do so by cancelling the [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) or returning false from your confirm function. (2) When the function is defined in a [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) other than the [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_scope) one, it cannot be found from the global scope.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get form with JavaScript (I used `id` in my example)
2. Add submit event listener (fires when form is submitted)
3. Do what ever you want to do on submit

```js
function confirmFunction(event) {
  const okToContinue = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (okToContinue === false) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  confirmFunction(event);
});
```

```html
<form id="form" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Label</label>
    <input type="text" name="value" placeholder="value" value='value'>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```